# I don't understand the algorithm for solving equations of the form $x^n \equiv 1 \mod m$

Tags: number-theory

Given a congruential equation of the form $x^n \equiv 1 \mod m$, according to my course notes all I have to do is to find a primitive root $a \mod m$ and then the solutions to the equation are of the form:
$x = a^i \mod m$ for $0 \leq i \leq \phi(m) - 1$.

If I take the equation $x^5 \equiv 1 \mod 11$, a primitive root $\mod 11$ is $2$. So, now I just have to plug the $i$-s. So for $i=1, x= 2^1 \mod 11$, but $(2 \mod 11)^5 \not\equiv 1 \mod 11$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a primitive root modulo $m$.  For a given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, suppose we want solutions to $x^n \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.  Since $a$ is a primitive root, we'll have $x^n \equiv (a^k)^n \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ that needs to be determined.

Note that $a^{kn} \equiv 1 \pmod{m} \iff kn$ is a multiple of $\phi(m)$.  If we let $kn$ be the least common multiple of $n$ and $\phi(m)$, then: 
$$\displaystyle kn = \operatorname{lcm}(n, \phi(m)) = \frac{n\phi(m)}{\gcd(n, \phi(m))}$$
Dividing both sides by $n$ yields a good formula for $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Try other values of $i$.

$(2^{2k})^5 \equiv 1 \mod 11, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$